# Running 3-Tier T-SQL Query for Report

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

First question here so please excuse any mistakes...

I am trying to write a SQL Query for an SSRS report and I am totally confused when it comes to my joins.

Background: I have 3 tables that are relevant

- **Publishers** - This is essentially a list of people
- **Publisher Reports** - This is a list of records (related to the Publisher table) that details the work they have completed in a month period.
- **Report Months** - This is a list of records (related to the Publisher Reports table) that relates to a specific month and year. On these records they have an indicator to show whether they relate to the previous six month period.

What i am trying to do is get a list of Publishers who have not submitted a publisher report that is related to a Report Month record within the last 6 months. My desired output is a list of Publishers in on column with the Report Month(s) that they are missing in the next column.

I am really struggling how to do it... I had thought of it as a three step process...

--STEP 1 - Get list of report months that are included in the last 6 months

```
WITH ACTIVE6MREPM AS
(
SELECT          r.jajw_name,
                r.jajw_CalendarDate
FROM            jajw_reportmonthBase r
WHERE           r.jajw_IncludedIn6MonthReport = '1'
),

--STEP 2 - Get list of all publishers
ACTIVEPUBS AS
(
SELECT          c.FullName,
                c.ContactId
FROM            ContactBase c
WHERE           c.statecode = '0'
AND             c.jajw_CongregationAssignment != 640840001 
AND             c.jajw_CongregationAssignment != 640840006 
AND             c.jajw_CongregationAssignment != 640840005
--AND               q.jajw_FieldServiceGroups = (@Field_Service_Group)
),

--STEP 3 - Get List of Publisher Reports for the selected Report Months
RELEVANTREPORTS AS
(
SELECT          r.jajw_reportId AS Publisher_Report_GUID,
                r.jajw_PublisherId AS Publisher_GUID,
                r.jajw_ReportMonthId AS ReportMonth_GUID,
                m.jajw_name AS ReportMonth_Name
FROM            jajw_reportBase r
INNER JOIN      jajw_reportmonthBase m ON r.jajw_ReportMonthId = m.jajw_reportmonthId
WHERE           r.jajw_ReportPeriod6Month = '1'
ORDER BY        m.jajw_CalendarDate
```

After these three, I want to create my list as described above and this is the bit that has me stumped! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: How are the tables related? Where are the ID fields? Perhaps it might be better if you provide some data for each of the 3 tables. The query itself shouldn't be complicated but your CTEs are confusing me.

Comment: Why do CTE's confuse you @anand

Comment: @scsimon, not CTEs in general, lol. These particular CTEs are not helping in understanding relationships between the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can shorten your code a lot... here's a shot at it without having test data... be sure to read the comments and add in the join condition and check the where clause.

```
with cte as(
SELECT          r.jajw_reportId AS Publisher_Report_GUID,
                r.jajw_PublisherId AS Publisher_GUID,
                r.jajw_ReportMonthId AS ReportMonth_GUID,
                m.jajw_name AS ReportMonth_Name,
                c.FullName,
                c.ContactId
FROM            jajw_reportBase r
INNER JOIN      jajw_reportmonthBase m ON 
                r.jajw_ReportMonthId = m.jajw_reportmonthId
INNER JOIN      ContactBase c on                           --what ever condition is appropiate
WHERE           r.jajw_ReportPeriod6Month = '1'
                and m.jajw_IncludedIn6MonthReport = '1'    --maybe put this here, or does the above do the same thing?
ORDER BY        m.jajw_CalendarDate)

select 
    p2.FullName,
    p2.ReportMonth_Name
from cte p
right join(select distinct 
                ReportMonth_Name, FullName 
            from ContactBase 
            left join jajw_reportmonthBase on 1=1) p2 on p2.FullName = p.FullName and p2.ReportMonth_Name = p.ReportMonth_Name  
where 
    ContactId in (select ContactId from cte group by ContactId having count(distinct ReportMonth_GUID) < 6)
    and p.FullName is null
```

**Here is an example using test data.**

```
declare @pub table (pubname varchar(56), ReportMonthName varchar(16))
insert into @pub (pubname,ReportMonthName) values
('a','Jan'),
('a','Feb'),
('a','Mar'),
('a','Apr'),
--publisher a is missing May and Jun
('b','Jan'),
('b','Feb'),
('b','Mar'),
('b','Jun')
--publisher b is missing Apr and May

declare @dt table (ReportMonthName varchar(16))
insert into @dt (ReportMonthName) values
('Jan'),
('Feb'),
('Mar'),
('Apr'),
('May'),
('Jun')



select 
    p2.pubname
    ,p2.ReportMonthName
from @pub p
right join(
select distinct
    p.pubname
    ,d.ReportMonthName
from @pub p
left join @dt d on 1=1)p2 on p2.pubname = p.pubname and p2.ReportMonthName = p.ReportMonthName where p.pubname is null
```

Comment: Hi @scsimon Thank you very much for the help! The only trouble is that this gives me the Publishers who have a report missing (which is what i want) but it shows me the report months they HAVE submitted a report. I want a list of Publishers who have a report missing along with which report months are missing. Does that make sense?

Comment: @JoelAbbott i edited the answer to fix that, hopefully. it's hard to do without your data. I provided some test data so you can see the logic in case it needs tweaking.

Comment: You, sir, are a genius!! Worked a treat!! Thank you so very much for your help